# Custom task form in a sharepoint workflow using vs2010

Tags: workflow

How can i use different approval task forms in each approval steps in sharepoint custom workflow using vs2010.

How can i create new custom Approval task form for sharepoint 2010 using vs2010.

Thanks in advance
iqbalkmk

Answer (score 1):

To have custom forms for different approval steps. Create one content type for each approval step with its own form. Then let each different step have its own content type. Voila!